# RegEx for IP address in non-standard log format

Tags: regex

Given the log message below I need to extract **ip-192-168-13-129** and turn it into **192.168.13.129**

```
{"path":"\/var\/log\/auth.log","message":"Jul 24 08:03:34 ip-192-168-13-129 sshd[32258]: Disconnected from user ubuntu 192.168.13.199 port 49540"}
```

Been playing around for a while and can't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state the language you are using, but in C# I think this would work for you:

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, 
   "ip-(\d{1,3})-(d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})", "$1.$2.$3.$4")
```